# Mac problem where I can't click on the Dock items and other functionality

Tags: mac

I'm currently using Mac 10.5 and suddenly, the icons in my Dock are unresponsive.  The functionality which disperse all my windows is not working either(it's the F3 functionality from the keyboard).  Does anyone know if maybe I have activated some locking mechanism by accident?  I can access the top menu bar of the OS as well as existing opened windows.

Comment: I just ran into this issue in 2021 on macOS 11.2. In addition to the Dock, cmd+tab switching didn't work. The original question is from 2009. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like your dock has died. If you can get into Terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal, I think), try `sudo killall Dock`. This'll crash-close the Dock, and it should restart happily. If it doesn't, logout and back in again.

Comment: still works on macOS 12 in 2021!